# Monitoring taskbar changes

Tags: c#

I am trying to monitor changes to the taskbar, e.g. when a new instance of Windows Explorer is started a new button is added. Likewise when I close an instance of Windows Explorer the button is removed. I need the monitoring to take place no matter what is added or  removed from the taskbar. I have tried the IUIAutomation Library, see below, and that will trigger an event when a new button is added to the taskbar but not when one is removed.

Any ideas on how to create such an event other than using automation shown below. Alternatively a global hook to monitor when any application is opened and any application is closed.

This is the automation question I posted previously below.

[IUIAutomation StructureChangedEventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495178/iuiautomation-structurechangedeventhandler)

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Would it work to monitor when a new process is launched, and then check to see if that process is displaying a window?

Comment: Yes that would suffice, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you looking for a process monitor?  Is there something wrong with the Process class?  Hooking to the taskbar requires DLL imports, registration, all kinds of jazz.  I'd recommend using Process if possible.  Plus, you won't get new windows for certain actions, like if "ShowInTaskbar = false;" for example.

Comment: Well I can use polling to count the buttons on the taskbar but I want an event to avoid the overhead. There is no event handlers in the process class for new process added or process removed so how do I monitor processes using events.

Comment: Consider a `WH_CBT` or `WH_SHELL` hook, which will inform you when a window is being created or destroyed (along with other events you will need to filter out). The [`SetWinEventHook` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) will allow you to get a bit more specific. Yes, *definitely* avoid polling. Speaking of avoiding, I noticed you also avoided answering my question about why you were trying to do this… Are you actually writing a shell replacement?